# Run a second project from within the same solution

Tags: c#, solution

I've been tasked with building a custom updater but are struggling with how to run this.
I could of course just create a separate app to take care of this but it is preferred that it all stay in the same solution.
In my solution I have the project "Main" which is a Forms application and the project "AutoUpdater" which is a console application.

[image: solution with two projects]

My idea was to have "Main" run the "AutoUpdater" console app in a separate process or possibly have the program copy the autoupdater.exe in a temp folder and then run it from there (to prevent file lock)

But how to I tell Main to run AutoUpdater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start` to run the AutoUpdater exe by providing the path.

Comment: Preferably in a BackgroundWorker ()

Comment: I was hoping that I could do this more dynamically instead of using Process.Start(direct path).
@Christian What benefits would it have to use background worker?

Comment: @SimonJensen What do you mean by "more dynamically"?

Comment: If there was any command that I could use to point to the project "AutoUpdater" so that I would not have to use a path string.

Comment: When the projects are compiled, the binaries don't work with projects. So you have to use a path to execute it.

Comment: You make a good point. I am still curious what benefits it would have to do this in a backgroundworker

Comment: I don't think there is a need for the BackgroundWorker here, as you don't wait for the process to end, it's a fire and forget type of thing. You may also need to use the ProcessStartInfo class to set more parameters regarding the process' execution

Comment: I'm not here to advocate the BackgroundWorker. However; any process or method call, not executed directly on the UI Thread (which is a very long list btw), should in my book be executed on a separate thread and picked up at convenience. BackGroundWorker made this task very easy. If you wanna _fire and forget_, dont pickup the response. But why forget? What if the update fails?

Comment: ClickOnce is a very good alternative in my experience for minor software kept inhouse in your company. It updates on every startup and you dont have to do a darn thing. Visual Studio will do it all for you. Except keeping the source updated. obviously :) You can find several guides on YouTube I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

in your main declare a using.

```
using AutoUpdater;
```

Then you have easy acces to start the Console.

Comment: This won't work, an Auto Updater needs to run as a separate process, or else it can't shut down and update the main app without being terminated itself while trying to do so.

Comment: @ilikeclassic That would still be run within the same process and I would run into file lock when trying to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AutoUpdater project's Post build event to copy the output to a location where the Main application can access.

Read more here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019

and/or you can add the AutoUpdater's directory to Path Environment variable and use just the executable name in Process.Start method.